# Choosing a prior for the intercept in a logistic regression with increased -INF probability?

Tags: logistic, bayesian, prior, stan

I am trying to fit a simple logistic regression of the kind:

> n ~ binomial(N, theta)
> theta = inv_logit(  a  +  x * b  )

where `x` is either 0 or 1 depending if a condition is present or not. Therefor the intercept `a` is directly linked to the probability `theta` for condition 0.

From what I read most people recommend a non-informative normal(0,10) prior for `a`, but this is always for centered data. I am modeling with `rstanarm`, which is centering the data (and I think the priors as well?) internally, so I would suspect that the prior I choose should be closer to the raw data I expect and not the centered one, is this correct?

In my data, I know that I have a lot of cases where I have no observations `n` in condition 0,  therefor `theta` tends to zero  and `a` would tend to `-inf`. Shouldn't this be reflected by a prior which gives a higher density to `-inf`Values (e.g. a gamma(1,0.5) distribution (but trying it gives me the error below).

```
Chain 4: Rejecting initial value:
Chain 4:   Log probability evaluates to log(0), i.e. negative infinity.
Chain 4:   Stan can't start sampling from this initial value.
```

Summarizing the Question:

- Do I have to account for the centering of the the priors in `rstanarm`.
- If not, what would be a appropriate prior for the intercept, if `-inf` has a high probability.

Comment: What do you mean by *zero inflated intercept*?

Comment: right, that's a stupid/wrong way of wording that. What I meant is, that the intercept tent to -inf  so theta would be 0 in case of condition x = 0

Comment: Can you please then update your post, editing a better explanation? Not everybody reads comments ...

Comment: The prior on `a` in `rstanarm::stan_glm` represents your beliefs about the expected log-odds of success for an observation with an average value of `x`. Although people do put normal(0, 10) priors on that, rarely do they understand what they are doing. If you execute `plot(density(plogis(rnorm(10^6, mean = 0, sd = 10)), from = 0, to = 1))` in R, you will see almost all the prior probability is less than 0.2 or greater than 0.8 with intermediate values being implausible. The default is normal with an expectation of zero and a standard deviation of 1.4, which yields almost uniform probabilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the visualization is really striking.

And thanks for explaining that the prior for 'a' would be for an average 'x'. Would you mind explaining why it's not for 'x=0' (or point me to a reference for that).